# Trace without file name and line number in Haxe

Tags: haxe

Haxe has `trace()`, which can be used on all targets to print contents.

```
trace("aa"); // Main.hx:89: aa
```

How do I print just the contents, without the file name and line number?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For sys targets (eg. neko, php, cpp, java, cs):

[`Sys.println(message);`](http://api.haxe.org/Sys.html#println)

For other targets, it depends on how you want to print the trace statement. For example, it can be customised for JS target:

```
haxe.Log.trace = function(msg, ?pos) js.Browser.window.console.log("trace: " + msg);
trace("ok?"); //will log to the console: trace: ok?
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Sys.print()

Comment: Also as a shortcut you can do "import Sys.*;" and then just "println('hello');" or "print('hello');"